# jQuery keyup event is activated multiple times, doubling every time it's triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, keyup

I added an auto-completing search bar to my website. It queries the database for elements that start with the entered string every time the user types a new character.

It works fine, however every time the user adds another character or does any keyboard event like backspace it doubles the event activation. 1,2,4,8,16, etc.. times.

How could I make it so that it doesn't accumulate event triggers and only triggers .keyup() one time per keyboard event?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<form>
<div class="nav-item">
    <input class="search-query form-control" placeholder="Items" 
       type="text"  name="items" value="" id="id1" />
</div>
</form>
<hr>
<div id="id2">
</div>
```

And here's the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').keyup(function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    $.get('/url/', {items: query}, function(data){
      $('#id2').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There's a missing `});` in your snippet. Apart from that It looks ok, can you share your data code?

Comment: You might look into a throttling or debouncing function ... but I don't know if that would resolve your underlying problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix it.

For anyone interested, here's how I did it:

(Obviously more experienced user please feel free to correct me if I am wrong!)

Basically, adding a [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method solved it. As it detaches the event from the `"#id1"` element by only executing it once.

Here's the **functional** code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').one("keyup", function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    $.get('/url/', {items: query}, function(data){
      $('#id2').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

For comparison here's the **old** one as posted above again:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#id1').keyup(function(){
    var query = $(this).val();
    $.get('/url/', {items: query}, function(data){
      $('#id2').html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You saved my day! Thank you! Though  I still wondered why keyup() method will cause problem...

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var lastTime = Date.now(), milisecondsToWait = 2000;//Here we will wait 2 seconds
  $('#id1').keyup(function(){
    if(Date.now() - lastTime >= milisecondsToWait){//And here
      var query = $(this).val();
      $.get('/url/', {items: query}, function(data){
        $('#id2').html(data);
        lastTime = Date.now(); //And finally here
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't solve the problem. It does make everything smoother, but keyup() is still being triggered exponentially many times!